# CUDA toolkit error on MAC: unable to open output file 'vectorAdd.o':, Permission denied

Tags: macos, cuda

I am trying to run CUDA toolkit on MAC, but when I am compiling CUDA sample programs I get this error:

> unable to open output file 'vectorAdd.o': 'Error opening output file
>   'vectorAdd.o': Permission denied'

I checked the environmental variables and the driver installation and everything seems OK.

Do you have some clue what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Momir

Comment: Directory permissions? Did you install the toolkit as root and are trying to build as a regular user?

Comment: I installed it as a root user and trying to build it also as a root.

Comment: how exactly do you invoke the compilation process?

Comment: make -C 0_Simple/vectorAdd. Just like from the documentation. I navigate from the home directory to /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/samples and then invoke the above command.

Comment: So no sudo and not as root?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not use sudo and root directory for installation of the toolkit. Eveything is done with the home directory and admin user.

Comment: OK, thanks talonmies for pointing out on this difference. The problem was that toolkit is installed as root but I was trying to build it as adim user.

Answer (score 15):

If you copy the whole samples folder and its contents to your home directory, you should be able to compile the samples there without `sudo`.

The problem is that the directories which contain the sample files are owned by root and not writable by admin users, so the compiler cannot create the new output files and folders it needs if you are running as an admin user.

If you want to compile the samples in situ (as the installation guide seems to suggest), you can compile them using `sudo`. Alternatively you can change the ownership of the samples directory and its subdirectories recursively:

```
sudo chown -R your-user-name /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/samples
```

Comment: I also had same problem, your solution does help.

Comment: thanks, had this exact same problem and changing the owner of the samples solved the problem for me.